# How to update product store_view attributes (name, description) programmatically?

Tags: product, product-attribute, scope

There is possible to have different product name and description because these attributes have store_view scope.
Please take a look at screenshot
[image: store_view]

To update product programmatically code should be something like:

```
$sku = 'sku1';
$storeId = 0;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($sku,true, $storeId, true);

$_product->setShortDescription('short description');
$_product->setCustomAttribute("abc", 'abc');
$_product->save($_product);
```

But in that case product short_description attribute will be updated in all scopes.
**How to update product in selected store_view scope?**

Comment: change `$storeId = 0;` to `$storeId = ...your store id here...;`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this below:

```
$sku = 'sku1';
$storeId = 0;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

$attribute_code = 'short_description';
$value = 'short description';

$product->addAttributeUpdate($attribute_code, $value, $storeId);
```

Comment: This will update "store" scope, but not "store_view" scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can also update a products attribute by scope if it's the default content, (name, sku, short description etc), using the product action class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action`

```
  use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action as ProductAction;
  ...
  protected ProductAction $productAction;
  
  public function __construct(
    ProductAction $productAction
    ...
  ) {
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $productId
   */
  public function updateData(int $productId)
  {
    $storeId = 4;
    $value = 'short description';
    $this->productAction->updateAttributes([$productId], ['short_description' => $value], $storeId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change the store ID like @Dimitri suggested, or switch to the csv uploader. I find that to be the easiest option for bulk updating attributes. All you need to use a CSV is 2 columns, one with the sku, and other with the attribute that you want to update

Comment: I aware of that CSV import possibility, but use custom product import and need some solution for multilanguage product import.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will have same issue (please ignore incorrect object injection):

```
        $sku = '7550055';
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($sku);
        $_product->setName('Russian name');
        $_product->setData('store_view_code', 'russian');
        $_product->setData('description', 'russian description');
        $_product->save($_product);
```

Take a note if product previously created without *store_view_code* field - attributes will be changed in all **store_view** scopes of current store.